# OTRS web service - How to get Ticket's TimeUnit

Tags: web-services, soap, otrs

As mentioned in the title I need to get Ticket's **TimeUnit** via OTRS soap service (v 3.3). It is standard field used in create Ticket service.
The problem is that GetTicket service receives all the expected fields but TimeUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I have explored OTRS docs and all the stuff I see that standard open source version of OTRS does not support getting TimeUnit field with GetTicket operation (in GenericInterface).
The only way is to add the functionality by developing source code of GenericInterface or by adding external OTRS plugin (if exists).
It is not a configuration matter.